# Convert characters to Upper Case in DataGridView

Tags: winforms, c++-cli, casing

My form contains several DataGridView controls that have two columns.  I want the data that the user types into column 1 to be converted to upper case.  The data in column 0 is read only and is populated by my program.  It is numeric and does not need to be converted to upper case.  The code below works but I'm wondering if there's a better way.

```
private: System::Void dataGridView_patterns_EditingControlShowing(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs^  e)
    {
        // This event sets the character casing to upper for the patterns.  It is called once per pattern.

        TextBox^ myControl;

        myControl = (TextBox^)(e->Control);
        myControl->CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing::Upper;
    }
```

The only problem that I have with this code is that the EditingControlShowing event is called once for every row in the DataGridView.  Is there a way to set the CharacterCasing to Upper one time for the control, or does it have to be set for every row to work properly?  I don't notice any performance issues, but it just seems unnecessary to set the casing for every row in the control.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom `DataGridTextBoxColumn` shown here:

[How to set DataGridView columns text format to uppercase by adding new property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001754/how-to-set-datagridview-columns-text-format-to-uppercase-by-adding-new-property)

Comment: Hi Jared,  Thanks for your answer.  I actually read that thread before I posted my question.  It seemed like a lot of work with no payback.  I'm surprised that Microsoft doesn't provide a CharacterCasing Property for the columns of a DataGridView.  The best place to program it would be in the Edit Columns dialogue of the DataViewGrid control.  Oh well preaching to the choir I'm sure. :o)  Thanks again for taking the time to review and respond to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Just to close out this thread, I used the code in my original question.  I guess that's the easiest way to set the casing in a DataGridView control.